# Error when completing purchase on Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I launch a purchase using the following code:

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, CoreApp.SKU_CHAPTER2, 10001, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "");
```

then I have the mPurchaseFinishedListener:

```
mPurchaseFinishedListener= new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase)
            {
                Log.d("Finish Purchase","Started");
                if (result.isFailure()) {
                    Log.d("Finish Purchase","Failure "+result.getMessage());
                    return;
                }

                if (purchase.getSku().equals(CoreApp.SKU_CHAPTER2)) {
                    CoreApp.in_app_chapter_2 = true;
                }
}
```

But after the purchase, the mPurchaseFinishedListener is not being executed though even I get the dialog Payment Successful, I know it because the line `CoreApp.in_app_chapter_2 = true` is not being executed. Why is the listener mPurchaseFinishedListener not being executed?